# How to create a database from a model .dbml

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I have a project that was previously connected to a database SQL Server 2012, but now I want to connect to a local database.

How to create a local database on the model .dbml?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programatically:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2008/11/21/linq-to-sql-dbml-more-than-just-for-accessing-a-db.aspx